# How to fit a truncated distribution to binned data?

Tags: distributions, dataset, descriptive-statistics, curve-fitting, histogram

I have the age at deaths data in the form of intervals ie 0-4, 5-9, 10-14, ... 80 & above years.I have converted inclusive class intervals to exclusive class intervals ie

age: 0-4.5, 4.5-9.5, 9.5-14.5, 14.5-19.5, 19.5-24.5, 24.5-29.5, 29.5-34.5, 34.5-39.5, 39.5-44.5, 44.5-49.5, 49.5-54.5, 54.5-59.5, 59.5-64.5, 64.5-69.5, 69.5-74.5, 74.5-79.5, 79.5-90.5

The data is number of deaths occurred in these intervals.

freq: 1219, 449, 784, 697, 868, 2097, 3287, 4186, 4186, 3369, 2377, 1384, 861, 477, 293, 166, 72

I am assuming that this data following weibull distribution. Last interval is open interval so that for my own interest i have removed beyond 90 years part of the distribution. That means i have truncated the distribution at T=90, distribution become right truncated weibull distribution. I have taken the middle value of these intervals as a x values. I have used maximum likelihood estimation method but likelihood equation are not in explicit form so that I have used optim() function. But I have got some warnings. Although I have proceed with warnings and the fit the distribution. This how i fit

```
x=c(2.25,seq(7,77, 5), 85)
x
f=c(1219, 449, 784, 697, 868, 2097, 3287, 4186, 4186, 3369, 2377, 1384, 861, 477, 293, 166, 72)
f              #no. of deaths at each class interval as a frequency's
N=sum(f)
T=90      #truncated point
data=data.frame(x,f)
rtwd=function(par, data){
p=par[1]
k=par[2]
T=90
N=sum(f)
logl=N*log(p)-N*log(k)+(p-1)*sum(f*log(x/k))-sum(f*((x/k)^p))-N*log(1-exp(-(T/k)^p))
return(-logl)
}
optim(par=c(2,20), rtwd, data=data, method="BFGS", hessian=T)

#fitting the right truncated weibull distribution
p=2.510924                   # parameters values given by optim() function but with some warnings
k=42.629044
x1=c(0, seq(4.5,79.5, 5))    # fitting purpose i have take lower limit of the class intervals
x1 
cdf=pweibull(x1, p, k, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)
cdf
trun=1-exp(-(T/k)^p)
trun
truncdf=cdf/trun
truncdf
prob=c()
a.cdf=c()
for(i in 1:(length(x1)-1)){
a.cdf[1]=f[1]
prob[i]=truncdf[i+1]-truncdf[i]
a.cdf[i+1]=a.cdf[i]+f[i+1]}
prob                         #probabilities
a.cdf                        #actual data cdf
lastprob=append(prob,(1-sum(prob)),length(x1)-1)
lastprob                      # inserting last interval probability
p1=sum(lastprob)  
p1
ex.fre1=N*lastprob              # expected frequencies
ex.fre1
exp.cdf=c()
for(i in 1:16){
exp.cdf[1]=ex.fre1[1]
exp.cdf[i+1]=exp.cdf[i]+ex.fre1[i+1]}
exp.cdf
#I have used kolmogoro-smirno test
ks.test=abs(a.cdf-exp.cdf)
ks.test
max=max(ks.test) 
max
cmax=1.36/sqrt(N)
cmax
plot(x,f, type="o")
par(new=T)
lines(x,ex.fre1)
```

I have got the curve like this
[image]

This is right truncated weibull distribution i have used

[image]

My doubts is i am not get good estimators, so that it is not good fit.

How to get good estimators for grouped data?

I have stuck in estimation procedure. Which iteration method can handle that kind of equations?

How to fit right truncated weibull distribution (or any appropriate distribution) to the grouped data?

And how to fit over the histogram?

Comment: You need a small [*reproducible example*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Then your question might be able to be migrated to a suitable place (one for which programming questions are not [off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)).

Comment: Please anybody suggest me something

Comment: I already suggested you give a reproducible example. Your code doesn't run when pasted into R because "grouped.data" is not a function in the distribution of R; I expect it's in a package you haven't specified the loading of. Your problem is that R looks like a factor, which `density` won't work on. You need actual data, which means you must somehow turn your counts into actual values in each bin. You might for example assuming a uniform distribution within each bin (it's unlikely, but it would correspond to a pdf that looks exactly like your histogram)

Comment: @Glen_b Yes sorry sir..grouped.data function is from "actuar" package. Even i don't know data follows which distribution? My attempt is to fit appropriate distribution to this data. I am able to produce only histogram but i don't know how to fit any distribution over the histogram?. Sorry for mistakes again.

Comment: Is your question mainly about how to choose a distributional approximation, or how best to fit distributions to binned data (both statistical questions), or about how to approximately estimate a kde for grouped data (a mostly statistical question) or is it "what commands do I use in R to draw a density to make this work?" (which is an R programming question)?

Comment: @Glen_b Actually I have both questions sir. How best to fit distributions to binned data ? and what commands do I use in R to draw a density to make this work? I have tried distribution fitting (Right Truncated wiebull)  by taking the midpoint of the class interval its quite good fit. But how to fit over the histogram? I can't able to understand.

Comment: Your question was closed because it looks like an R programming question ("what R commands to use" is generally off topic). Please edit to focus more on the statistical aspects (which I believe would be on topic). If I get a few minutes I may be able to make an attempted edit along the lines you indicated myself

Comment: @Glen_b dear sir My main question is how to fit grouped data?

Comment: Actual curve-of-deaths data is usually at least bimodal (a peak at the youngest ages and another somewhere in late middle age, and sometimes one around age 20ish). A typical example is [here](https://www.longevitas.co.uk/site/images/ELT15.png) -- so a unimodal distribution like the Weibull probably won't fit all that well over the whole range. I note that people that model wind speed often have binned data to which they frequently fit Weibull distributions so it might be worth investigating some of that (we may even have a question or two on site, you could try a search). ... ctd

Comment: ctd. .. You could treat the data past 90 as *censored* rather than truncating it; this is especially convenient with the Weibull (survival models are designed to do just that). In addition some survival programs can deal with interval-censored data (i.e. binned data).

Comment: I note you previously asked a question like this; it would have been better to fix that one than post a new, only slightly different one. I will close the earlier one as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: @Glen_b Yes sir..but i am using all the data (ie all the samples N=26772). I am not leaving some of the data to censor it (bit confusion??) that means uncesored units= 26772 and censored units=0..!!!!(??) So that I am very confused whether i should do truncation or censoring..???

Comment: please suggest me something more..

Comment: If you're calling all the data past 90 ">90" without retaining its individual value, then it's definitely right-censored. (strictly speaking the data within the bounded bins is actually also censored, that's the more general case of interval censoring).

Comment: I don't see any reason to think that your problem is anything other than the fact that the Weibull cannot be a good fit for data where there's a conspicuous second mode at the lowest age group (as already discussed but which you don't seem to have engaged with in any fashion). I see nothing to suggest that there's anything but a poor model choice here causing the problem you see.

Comment: @Glen_b sorry for late reply (inconvenience of internet). I am engaged with this problem only sir. I have again tried with doubly truncated distribution, only observing 15-65 age group (I can send this coding also if u say send). Although weibull is not good fitted. Actually I don't want to lose the 0-15 age information, and we can observed that 0-4 age group has also more deaths i.e., mother to child transmission of HIV is more. Somehow i want to fit one distribution to the 0-15 age group and another distribution to the above 15 years age groups. In this regard suggest me something.